# Slick Slider - remove slide then reattach it

Tags: jquery

I have a slider and I can remove each slide when clicking on it. I know how to add slides:

```
$('.slider').slick('slickAdd',HTML_HERE);)
```

but I want to somehow store the removed slide info somewhere so that I can restore each removed slide on a button click.

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="item" id="item-one">
    <div class="close-item">
      x
    </div>
    <h3>
      Item One
    </h3>
    <p>
      Item One Text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="item-two">
    <div class="close-item">
      x
    </div>
    <h3>
      Item Two
    </h3>
    <p>
      Item Two Text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="item-three">
    <div class="close-item">
      x
    </div>
    <h3>
      Item Three
    </h3>
    <p>
      Item Three Text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="item-four">
    <div class="close-item">
      x
    </div>
    <h3>
      Item Four
    </h3>
    <p>
      Item Four Text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="item-five">
    <div class="close-item">
      x
    </div>
    <h3>
      Item Five
    </h3>
    <p>
      Item Five Text
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control">
<button for="item-one">
Resore Item 1
</button>
<button for="item-two">
Resore Item 2
</button>
<button for="item-three">
Resore Item 3
</button>
<button for="item-four">
Resore Item 4
</button>
<button for="item-five">
Resore Item 5
</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  margin: 0 15px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}

.close-item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.box').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: true,
  centerMode: false,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: false,
  autoplay: false
});

$(".close-item").on('click', function() {
  var slideIndex = $(this).parent();
  $('.box').slick('slickRemove', $('.slick-slide').index(slideIndex));
});
```

Is there a way to store each slide's html and pull it back?

https://jsfiddle.net/idoangel/wxu5fzhr/19/

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Just appending the HTML to a hidden element each time, then restoring from it.

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="item" for="item-one">
    <div class="close-item">
      x
    </div>
    <h3>
      Item One
    </h3>
    <p>
      Item One Text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" for="item-two">
    <div class="close-item">
      x
    </div>
    <h3>
      Item Two
    </h3>
    <p>
      Item Two Text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" for="item-three">
    <div class="close-item">
      x
    </div>
    <h3>
      Item Three
    </h3>
    <p>
      Item Three Text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" for="item-four">
    <div class="close-item">
      x
    </div>
    <h3>
      Item Four
    </h3>
    <p>
      Item Four Text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" for="item-five">
    <div class="close-item">
      x
    </div>
    <h3>
      Item Five
    </h3>
    <p>
      Item Five Text
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="save-box">
  <div class="save-button" for="item-one">
    <button>
      Restore One
    </button>
    <div class="hidden">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="save-button" for="item-two">
    <button>
      Restore Two
    </button>
    <div class="hidden">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="save-button" for="item-three">
    <button>
      Restore Three
    </button>
    <div class="hidden">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="save-button" for="item-four">
    <button>
      Restore Four
    </button>
    <div class="hidden">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="save-button" for="item-five">
    <button>
      Restore Five
    </button>
    <div class="hidden">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  margin: 0 15px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}

.close-item:hover, button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.save-box {
  margin-top: 15px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.save-button {
  margin: 0 15px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.box').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: true,
  centerMode: false,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: false,
  autoplay: false
});

$(".close-item").on('click', function() {
  var slideIndex = $(this).parent();
  var filterID = $(this).parent().attr("for");
  var saveStuff = $(this).parent().html();
  $('.box').slick('slickRemove', $('.slick-slide').index(slideIndex));
  $(".save-button[for="+filterID+"] .hidden").append(saveStuff);
});

$(".save-button button").on("click", function() {
  var undoFor = $(this).parent().attr("for");
  var savedHTML = $(this).parent().find(".hidden").html();
  $('.box').slick('slickAdd','<div class="item" for='+undoFor+'>'+savedHTML+'</div>');
  $(this).parent().find(".hidden").empty();
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/idoangel/wxu5fzhr/103/